# jQuery only hover if scrollTop = 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrolltop

I would like to add a hover effect to my header, but only if the user is at the top of the page. I´m working with shopify and I think the best way to do so is that it adds a class when you hover over it and change some CSS properties (like text-color and height). I already got this code which does the same if you scroll. Can I edit this code so it does the same if you hover over the element, but only if `scrollTop = 0`?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function() {

    $(document).on('shopify:section:load', function(event) {      
      jQuery(window).trigger('resize').trigger('scroll');

      var Heightcalculate = $('header').height(); 
      // Responsive edits
      if( $(window).width() > 980){  
        //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
        var header = $(".scrollheader");
        $(window).scroll(function() {
          var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

          if (scroll >= 1 ) {
            header.removeClass('scrollheader').addClass("coverheader");
            $('#phantom').show();
            $('#phantom').css('height', Heightcalculate+'px');
          } else {
            header.removeClass("coverheader").addClass('scrollheader');
            $('#phantom').hide();
          }
        });        
      }
      $('.no-fouc').removeClass('no-fouc');
      $('.load-wait').addClass('hide');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

On hover, check `$.scrollTop()`, and add class if it's 0.

```js
var $header = $(".scrollheader");
$header.hover(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
    $header.addClass('hovered');
  }
},function() {
  if ($header.hasClass('hovered')) {
    $header.removeClass('hovered');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 500vh;
}
.scrollheader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
.hovered {
  background: #171717;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="scrollheader">header</header>
```

You could also use an event listener on scroll, and if someone's at the top of the page, add a class indicating that, then trigger a CSS hover on that class.

```js
$header = $('.scrollheader');
$(window).on('scroll',function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0 && ! $header.hasClass('top')) {
    $header.addClass('top');
  } else if ($header.hasClass('top')) {
    $header.removeClass('top');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 500vh;
}
.scrollheader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
.top:hover {
  background: #171717;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="scrollheader top">header</header>
```

Comment: thank you. Is it possible to add the class by default and remove it by hovering? kinda like the opposite. I also need to change the default background-img src of the class #actuallogo and the text-color of .scrollheader...

Comment: @Geatrix you're welcome. If you have another question, you should make another post. You should have a single, clear question per post and keep the details in the post itself.

Comment: thanks. i´m trying it out now. I edited the code like this:     $header.removeClass('nohover');
  }
},function() {
  if (!$header.hasClass('nohover')) {
    $header.addClass('nohover');
  }

Comment: this works but it doesn´t remove the .nohover class when the user has scrolled. What do you think?